# React - How to set source of an image to a imported file within an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Not sure how to word this properly so I’ll share a few bits of code.

```
import {
  ClearSkys,
  MainlyClear,
  PartlyCloudy,
  Overcast,
} from "../images/images";
```

From there I have an object calling those

```
const [images, setImages] = useState({
    0: {
      src: { ClearSkys },
      disc: "Clear skys",
    },
    1: {
      src: { MainlyClear },
      disc: "Mainly Clear",
    },
    2: {
      src: { PartlyCloudy },
      disc: "Partly Cloudy",
    },
    3: {
      src: { Overcast },
      disc: "Overcast",
    }
})
```

And now I want to call that object to set a image SRC. I try

```
<img src={images[0].src} />
```

I don’t call it exactly that way but the way I do gets to the same end point. This doesn’t work for me, any way to call it like this?

Comment: What are the values you are importing? Are they sources? Are they objects?

Answer (score 1):

your state is an object not an array
you can simply access the value doing this

```
<img src={images.0.src} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're updating the `src` property as an object, so for the obvious reason if you read value as `images[0].src`, it won't display the image because `src` value is `{ClearSkys:"image"}`

To fix this,

1. you should set state without an object, so

   src: { ClearSkys }

should be

```
src: ClearSkys
```

2. while reading, you need `images.0.src`

Answer (score 0):

Use a list to store all your images and data related to the image and map your list.

```
import img1 from "../images/images"
import img2 from "../images/images"


const data = [{
 src:img1,
 alt: 'text describing image',
},
{
 src: img2,
 alt: 'text describing image',
}
]

{data.map((item, idx) =>
  <img src={item.src} alt={item.alt} />
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
const ImageSrource = "../images/images/"

const [images, setImages] = useState({
    0: {
      src: ImageSource + "image1.extention",
      disc: "Clear skys",
    },
    1: {
      src: ImageSource + "image2.extention",
      disc: "Mainly Clear",
    },
    2: {
      src: ImageSource + "image3.extention",
      disc: "Partly Cloudy",
    },
    3: {
      src: ImageSource + "image4.extention",
      disc: "Overcast",
    }
})
```

`image4.extention` would be `imageName.png` or what so ever image you have.

`ImageSource + "image1.extention"` will make the src path in string `"../images/images/ClearSkys.svg"`